# Document.getElementById in global variable stops working when tab in tabbar is switched

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, getelementbyid, event-listener

As I learn by "doing" I find myself venturing into uncharted territory with the document.getElementById and addEventListener functions. I am using these functions for a small image (button) that will have — based on various steps the user takes — states of a) disabled, b) enabled, c) mouseover, d) mouseout, e) swap image, and f) various cursor styles.

Yesterday I spent a couple of hours reading through Stack Overflow and MDN Web Docs to understand how all the pieces work together. I then built the code and it worked perfectly. That's the good news. The bad news is this morning I just happened to click a tab on a tabbar (that exists on the same page) and when I went back to the original tab all of the event listeners had dropped and I do not understand why. By choosing "document" as my main target for the getElementById, I thought I was safe in that the event listeners and global variable would be active as long I was within the "document." Could someone help me understand what I'm missing? Here are the various steps I've taken:

I first declare the global variable

```
window.elem_populate = 0;
```

Then in the window.onload I apply a value to the variable. BTW, I use window.onload because the ID for the target was not being created in time and was throwing an "undefined" error.

```
elem_populate = document.getElementById("toolbar_populate");
```

Then, depending on input from the user I use this approach:

```
elem_populate.addEventListener('mouseover', hover_populate_on);
elem_populate.addEventListener('mouseout', hover_populate_off);
```

Here are a couple of examples of the functions being called:

```
hover_populate_off = function hover_populate_off() {
    elem_populate.style.opacity = "1.0";
    elem_populate.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
}

hover_populate_on = function hover_populate_on() {
    elem_populate.style.opacity = "0.8";
    elem_populate.style.cursor = "pointer";
}
```

The actual target ("toolbar_populate") is positioned on Tab 1 of a two-tab tabbar. If I don't move off the tab, everything works magically. But when I move to Tab 2 and then go back to Tab 1 all the references are lost and the functionality stops. Because everything is on the same document I'm not understanding why I'm losing the reference. Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance ...

Comment: If the reference is lost, it means that the element is removed from the document at some point. But we have no way to help you if we don't know how you manage your page's tabs

Comment: @blex I see. So the fact that it's all in the same "document" doesn't necessarily mean that all elements stay intact while I maneuver around within the document?

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS? There is really no need for JavaScript here

Comment: Yes, it all depends on how you show/hide your tab contents. If at some point you do `container.innerHTML = '...';`, any reference to elements that were inside that container is lost. If you used only CSS to show/hide things, then it would stay intact

Comment: @epascarello I do not know how to apply CSS for some of the stages I need. I can use :hover and the like, but if I want to "disable" and have a certain look, I don't know what selector to use. If you are saying that everything I described in my OP can be done through CSS, then I will pursue that angle. (Although, in the interest of learning I'll probably still look at what went wrong in my original code). Thank you.

Comment: @blex Thank you for providing me some direction here. I will take a look at the innerHTML and see what I can learn. Much appreciated.

Comment: If you replace content on the page with inerHTML it is like using a whiteboard. You are erasing all of the content in that element and replacing redrawing it. Any data that was in it is replaced. So either you should show and hide content, use event delegation, or you need to bind the events each time you add the elements.

Comment: `#toolbar_populate { opacity: 0.8; transition: opacity 0.3s; } #toolbar_populate:hover { opacity: 1; }`

Comment: @epascarello Sweet. I totally forgot about the #id selector. (So much to learn!). Now that covers the standard state and the hover state but now I need to find a way to 'simulate' disabled (e.g., opacity 0.5; pointer = not-allowed.) but I don't see how that can be done dynamically through CSS? It seems like only JS? Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: You can add a class for disabled, but you will need to add javascript to cancel the click since you will not be able to use `pointer-events: none` since you want to display a cursor.